# Index out of range in python programme

Tags: python, indexing

I've written a programme that is supposed to recognize words even if letters recur, for instance "JJJOOOHHHNNN" is supposed to be recognized as "JOHN", but when I run it, I get an error that index is out of range and don't know why it happens.
P.S. I know that there is a simpler way to do this, but I wanted to use re.match() and pop() function.

```
import re 
letters="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTQUWXYZ"
def recognize_name(name):
    name=name.upper()
    result=[]
    temp=len(name)
    while len(name)!=0:
        for j in letters:
            if re.match("^{0}+".format(j), name):
                name=list(name)
                while name[0] == j:
                    name.pop(0)
                name="".join(name)
            else:
                continue
        result+=j
    result="".join(result)
    return result
print(recognize_name("JJJOOOHHHNNN"))

Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
File "C:\Users\macie\OneDrive\Desktop\Folder\My_repo\plik2.py", 
line 11, in recognize_name
while name[0] == j:
File "C:\Users\macie\OneDrive\Desktop\Folder\My_repo\plik2.py", 
line 19, in <module>
print(recognize_name("JJJOOOHHHNNN"))
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] to include your code as code blocks rather than images?

Comment: I've just done it

Comment: Where does the error happen? A traceback would help you debug

Comment: Any reason V is missing from `letters`? Also - how'd this handle things like `ANNA` as a name?

Comment: @MadPhysicist in the 2nd screenshot of the first revision of the post... it'd be handy if you could also post that as a code block please Macios?

Comment: Sorry guys, I've just added error too.

Comment: There is an error with pop(). It looks as if in certain moment name was empty, but I don't know why

Comment: Jon Clements, such names would be treated as exceptions :D

Answer (score 0):

#### Runtime errors

The error occurs because `name` will eventually be reduced to 0 length, at which the check against `name[0]` won't be possible. This can be fixed by adding a check for `len(name) > 0`.

```python3
while len(name) > 0 and name[0] == letter:
```

Note that the `and` must be this way round in order to guard `name[0]`.

The program will also error on the line `result += j`. `+=` is used to join lists together; to add a single element to a list, call `result.append(j)`. This line should also be indented by one more level.

#### Logical errors

`V` is omitted from `letters`. To get a string of uppercase letters without having to type it manually and risk this kind of error, you can do

```python3
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
```

Final code:

```python3
import re
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters

def recognize_name(name):
    name=name.upper()
    result=[]
    temp=len(name)
    while len(name)!=0:
        for j in letters:
            if re.match("^{0}+".format(j), name):
                name=list(name)
                while len(name) > 0 and name[0] == j:
                    name.pop(0)
                name="".join(name)
            else:
                continue
            result.append(j)
    result="".join(result)
    return result
print(recognize_name("JJJOOOHHHNNN"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 problems. One is related to the index error, the other is the actual construction of the result (appending).

```py
while name[0] == j:
    name.pop(0)
```

This is removing ALL occurrences of the matched letter, until it is completely removed. The basic logic is fine, until you get to the last letter, which is popped, and then `name` becomes an empty string.

```py
# 1)
while name[0] == j:  # name = list('JJJOOOHHHNNN') , j: 'J'
    name.pop(0)  # name = 'JJOOOHHHNNN'

# 2)
while name[0] == j:  # name = list('JJOOOHHHNNN') , j: 'J'
    name.pop(0)  # name = 'JOOOHHHNNN'

# 3)
while name[0] == j:  # name = list('JOOOHHHNNN') , j: 'J'
    name.pop(0)  # name = 'OOOHHHNNN'

# 4) 
#  name[0] does not equal j anymore, so continue and append j to the result, 
#  so repeating consecutive letters get "collapsed" to 1

 ....

# Eventually, your name string will become 'NNN' > 'NN' > 'N'
# (I know it's actually a list at this point in the code)
while name[0] == j:  # name = ['N'] , j: 'J'
    name.pop(0)  # name = []

# Now name list it is empty! so
name[0]  # raises IndexError
```

So add a condition to that inner `while` loop, to make sure that there is contents in that list

```py
while name and name[0] == j:
```

Second issue, `result += j` is under-indented. It needs to be within the for loop

```py
for j in letters:

    . . . 

    result += j
```